# How to know which ceremony to select (5 possible options)?

Tags: cultist-simulator

Can someone explain me this behavior in game?
In red rectangle there is 4 possible ceremony, but i only start with ***An Ardent Orison*** (orange one). Why? What i am missing?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What you are trying to do there is to "upgrade" your acquaintance into a believer, in other words, change him from  "a friend" into a cultist follower. To do that, you must use your "Cult" card (Unflinching Order) + the acquaintance + a Forge Lore card. The reason is that Unflinching Order IS a Forge cult. Got it? ;) 
You don't even need the Health card.

Comment: Plus, to change the Believer to Disciple, you need 7 points of the Cult lore. In your case, 7 Forge. From Disciple to Exalt, 21 points.

Comment: @vianna77 Would you have any interest in turning those comments into an answer?

Comment: @Tashus , no... go ahead and answer if you want. This community is trigger-happy to downvote questions and answers! I have posted the same questions here and on Reddit for years. I always get downvoted here and always get a great answer on Reddit. I'm tired of this.